# So many unfillable captchas?

Tags: orbot, android, captcha

How do i avoid this problem; while orfox and orbot i get stuck in so many captchas and cant complete them properly? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that some sites like Cloudfare and Google are mass-accessed through your exit point. Use "SIGNAL NEWNYM" command to forcibly change your exit and try again.

Comment: @bloodfart I'm glad to help! Feel free to ask further questions!

Comment: Well one question have you got any suggestions about what smartphone is best suited to run tor?

Comment: @bloodfart a difficult question, actually. It must be an Android device that is able to be flashed with your own firmware. First of all, it must have at least 2 cores, 4 is better - to work properly. But it consumes battery ALOT : my Nexus 7 tablet lives one charge to 5-7 days without Tor, but 24-36 hours with Orbot on background. So use Philips Xenium - if you need a phone running Tor - they have a very good battery. Also 2-4 cores + good battery + 2+Gb ram device will suite you well.

Comment: Ok thank you i will not run it all the time, my current phone has 8 cores (4x cortex A53 @1500mhz and 4 x cortex A57 @ 2100mhz) and 4gb+ of RAM and an excellent battery i might just look into paying someone to root it, its an amazing phone

Comment: @bloodfart which model btw? And how big is it's battery? Take a look at [this precious](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/meet-the-android-phone-with-a-humungous-10000mah-battery-776134)

Comment: where I've to enter this command mentioned? It's possible do so it in tor browser for windows or linux? Thanks, Kathy

Comment: @kathy you have to enter it in telnet in any telnet client. Use the client you want, open a connection to a port mentioned in ControlPort directive, authenticate like that '`AUTHENTICATE "password"` and after `250 OK` response use the command. You can find existing or write your own very simple tool/browser add-on for sure